# Describing correlation between $M$ random variables

Tags: statistics, correlation

I'm new to statistics and I have been trying to find a "standard" way to describe the correlation between $M$ random variables. For simplicity, let's take $M$ to be 3 and define the three RVs $X,Y,$ and $Z$ with respect to three independent RVs $A,B,$ and $C$ such that:

$X=A$

$Y=A+B$

$Z=A+B+C$

How can we describe the pair-wise and triplet-wise correlation between $X,Y,$ and $Z$? Do three pair-wise correlations suffice?

Comment: You would probably get most attention at Cross-Validated: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, they are not sufficient. There are more complex issues that might happen.

For these situations it is interesting to analyze other statistics. There are [partial correlations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_correlation) and the [coefficient of determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination). Both involve linear regression.

In the first case, you model $X$ as a function of $Z$ using simple linear regression. The partial correlation $\rho_{XY.Z}$ (read correlation between $X$ and $Y$ discounted $Z$) is defined as the correlation between the residuals $e_x$ and $e_y$ of the regressions $X\sim Z$ and $Y\sim Z$. It represents the correlation of $X$ and $Y$ when discounted any possible effects from $Z$. Shuffle the random variable symbols around to compute $\rho_{XZ.Y}$ and $\rho_{YZ.X}$. Expanding to $M$ variables $V_1,...,V_M$, you have to consider $\rho_{V_iV_j.\mathbf{V}}$ where $\mathbf{V}$ is an arbitrary subset of $V_1,...,V_M$. Two by two correlation is not enough, but a full Covariance Matrix or Precision Matrix is.

In the second case, you want the $R^2$ statistic. Build a multiple regression with equation $Y=b_0+b_1X+b_2Y$, and $R^2$ will appear as the simplest indicator of model quality (but if the regression has any meaning for you, don't consider it your single quality indicator!), being a ratio of [Sums of Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet). $R^2$ can be seen as a composite correlation indicator.

Also, analyze other statistics and plot graphs. Check [Anscombe's Quartet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_sums_of_squares) to realize why - it is a set of four samples with completely different behavior and exactly same mean, variance and correlation.

Comment: Reading your answer, I guess there is no such thing as "triple" covariance of "triple" correlation, something like $E[XYZ]$ with a proper normalization.

Comment: I'm pretty sure someone developed a mathematical definition of triple covariance somewhere, but my theoretical probability is very rusty. Anyway, I haven't seen any real world application of it.